# Can't upload file to SFTP server using JSch - No such file (SftpException)

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server and upload a file. In my case I'm having to use a proxy and use private key for authentication. I was also given a specific location where the files need to be uploaded: `sftp://mycompany.host.de/uploads`

Below is my code snippet. I **can** establish a connection just fine and get authenticated as well via private key. But I face issues when trying to "put" transfer a file to remote server.
I don't think I'm correctly defining this string value for the destination.

I've seen some examples online where a the `username@host` is used to create some kind of URI, but I'm not sure how this is to be done. I've tried a few different things and cannot upload and I get a *"No such file"* exception. It can't be the source file, as this file exists.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity("path\\to\\privateKey"); // using private key authentication

session = jsch.getSession("myUser", "mycompany.host.de");
// (I understand the security threat here)
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

ProxySOCKS5 proxy = new ProxySOCKS5("mycompany.host.de", 8080);
proxy.setUserPasswd("myUser", null);
session.setProxy(proxy);

session.connect();
channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();

// this file does exist and I can retrieve it just fine
String sourcePath = "test/dummy.txt";  

// issue is here not to sure how set the "destination" properly
// (the remote destination file name)
String destinationPath = "sftp://mycompany.host.de/uploads/dummy.txt";
//                         "/mycompany.host.de/uploads/dummy.txt";

// EXCEPTION is thrown here, SftpException NO SUCH FILE.
channel.put(sourcePath, destinationPath); 

// do more stuff....

channel.disconnect();
channel.exit();
session.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 4):

The second argument of [`ChannelSftp.put`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is *"the remote destination **file name**"*, not a URL (but also not only a destination directory directory). So like this:

```
String destinationPath = "/uploads/dummy.txt";
```

---

If you are unsure of the remote path syntax, login with a GUI SFTP client, and see what path does it show. In case your account is not chrooted, the actual path might be like `/home/account/uploads/dummy.txt`.